# HAProxy add header based on URL parameter

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Using `HAProxy v1.6`

I'm doing Websocket request that currently (at least on javascript) won't support custom headers.

I'm trying to add a custom header at the HAProxy layer (before forwarding it to the load balancer) based on a get parameter

Example:

The next code works (on backend)

```
#match get-url someGetKey paramater
acl is_key_match        url_reg          \?(?:.*?)someGetKey=([\w|=]+)
#Add header
http-request set-header My-Custom-Header hardcoded_string if is_key_match
```

My goal is the to replace `hardcoded_string` with the first match group of the regex `\?(?:.*?)someGetKey=([\w|=]+)`

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
http-request set-header cookie %[urlp(SSession)] if is_sticky_url
```

`%[]` - variable
`url(SSession)` - HTTP-GET parameter with the key SSession

For that example, the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/path?sSession=abcd
```

will forward a request with the header:

```
cookie=abcd
```